# GAE: Trouble with push to deploy

Tags: git, google-app-engine

I have troubles with push to deploy to GAE today:

```
me:default me$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 376 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Scanning pack: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Storing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Processing commits: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Triggering release (if applicable)...
To https://source.developers.google.com/p/myappatgae/r/default
   2e8c8ca..c5457a0  master -> master
```

It seems like it's doing some stuff but it's never publishing the code.
I can see the code commit in the Google Developers Console. The edited files in question have the same edits when looking in the dev console repo browser. But it's not publishing. I see old results even minutes after the commit.

Comment: Is the version you just deployed marked as the default version in the console?  Check version number in app.yaml and make sure it is the default version in the console.

Comment: Yes, I really haven't changed the version lately (like in a few weeks). I have the same problem with two different instance/repo pairs, only starting today. I am starting to wonder if this is related to git config files - I am not sure what config file the GAE push-to-deploy checkouts are supposed to use (a wild guess is each checkout's .git/config), nor what config file they are currently using. I did try to add a global setting earlier today using this command: `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global ` in order to exclude .pyc files. I am not sure if that caused this.

Comment: I just tried on another computer (not used with GAE at all before): installing the cloud sdk, checking out the repo, editing a file, then commit+push+deploy, but got the same result. This leaves me with the belief that something over at Google is broken. Am I the only one on this??

Comment: It is does not work with modules right now. `Deployment failed, details: { Failed to load application, Line 5, column 7: Unable to find property 'module' on class: com.google.cloud.services.infrastructure.controller.appengine.PreparedAppYaml$PreparedAppYamlInner, none}`. You can check your error message in the "Release History" tab.

Comment: The latest release in the Release History is from my last deploy - a very old commit - yesterday (April 30, today is May 1) when this still worked. It just doesn't work today. Unfortunately this is too unstable for me (or I can't find my own error), so I reverted to using GAE Launcher for deploys.

Comment: Not sure if this is a valid question anymore but anyways, Google is taking the PTD further and implementing more features to it by using Jenkins - sounds good but I have yet to try it out.