# Getting push to deploy to work, configuring "release pipeline"

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine

So since last week suddenly `git push origin master` doesn't work anymore to "push to deploy". It sure pushes the sources to remote repository at Google, and the code is there but it never deploys. Read about it here: [GAE: Trouble with push to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23400892/gae-trouble-with-push-to-deploy)

It seems things are changing over at Google and this week there is new stuff in the Google Developer Console, in the "Cloud Development/Releases" section; "Configure Release Pipeline"

There are three settings: the pipeline name, pipeline tasks, and then an optional setting to have deploy notifications sent by email.

I just enter a random name like "mydevpipeline", select "Deploy source only", and check the email box. But I just get this error: "Failed to create the pipeline.". I also tried unchecking the email box, still same error. Tried it over and over.

No where to go from there...
Anyone been able to create this pipeline and get it all working?

It seems that this pipeline configuration must go through in order for push to deploy from now. I haven't seen any news or notification about this change...

Fwiw, the documentation https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/push-to-deploy states nothing about pipelines. It's just outdated I guess.

**Update:**

What do you know... I went on trying to configure this pipeline on the live GAE project (the one described above is the dev GAE project I'm using)... and it worked. I could configure a pipeline ok. After that, I could once more push-to-deploy, alas only on the *live* version so far. I might try creating a new dev project, it seems existing projects "break" from time to time... I have had similar problems before and creating a new project DOES solve things from time to time.....

Comment: Just a follow up: I get very few problems like the ones above recently. I think Google got their stuff working better with time... Still "git push origin master" always fails (Auth fails) on 1st run after not touching it for a while. 2nd try always work, I guess it refreshes the auth cookies after having failed once.

Comment: The documentation seems to be updated now... But I'm also having this issue

Comment: Update: I'm not sure but it seems like the old "release pipeline" described above is gone as of now. We have to use billable Jenkins setups? We have to PAY in order to push our OWN code? o_O

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine pipelines do not like `.gitignore` file. Try if it works without that file. It fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to get this working for PHP, after a lot of communication with Google it was finally revealed to me that in your app.yaml file you need to have a line that reads:

```
threadsafe: false
```

In order for the pipeline to successfully pick up and deploy your git push (I use sourcetree, but command line git has the same end result) that line must be present.  If it's omitted or set to true the pipeline won't be able to deploy it.

I wanted to throw this answer on here in case anyone stumbled on this thread looking for help.  One of my projects has "randomly broken" and after 3 months of successfully using my release pipeline for multiple commits per day it suddenly no longer deploys when I push.  Ultimately giving the extremely helpful error message of "Unable to get deployment status" - and now none of my changes can be applied to the live site.  Copying the entire source code, changing the app name, and pushing to a new GAE project with release pipeline works fine, but I need the original site to start working again.